# Seesaw logic problem

Tags: physics

[image]

The seesaw is divided equally into $6$ parts and is already tilted to the left side with the first $2$ blocks. Assuming all the green blocks weigh the same, which side would the seesaw tilt if the $3^{\text{rd}}$ block is placed on the right edge of the seesaw, or would the seesaw not tilt at all?

Is this question even solvable? What is the proof?

Comment: This question would be better served at Physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems to be identical to [this question at Yahoo! answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121103145202AAXRF5V).

Comment: i posted it on yahoo also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the moment about the center hinge to decide, which side it would tilt. 
Let the weight of each of the green squares be $w$ and the distance between the blue pointers be $a$.

The two green squares are placed at a distance of $\dfrac{3a}2$ to the left of the hinge while one green square is placed at a distance of $3a$ to the right of the hinge.

[image]

The clockwise moment about the center hinge due to two green squares on the left is given by $2w \times \dfrac{3a}2 = 3aw$.

The counter-clockwise moment about the center hinge due to one green square on the right extreme is given by $w \times 3a = 3aw$.

Hence, the net clockwise moment about the hinge is $3aw - 3aw = 0$. Hence, the seesaw won't tilt.

The plots in the question and the solution were made using [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

Comment: thanks. the picture was helpful.

Comment: But are we supposed to treat the blocks as points? This is a much more interesting problem if we don't.